# Javascript - Determine if user current location within KML layer of google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I am trying to check if user location / Google marker inside the KML layer or not.

Is there any event of KML to determine this?
Or I can check after marker placed on the google map?

Any idea?

My sample code is here.
is there any suggestion or sample code?
Waiting for your kind response.
Thanks in advance.

```
    var map;
    function initialize() {
        var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(49.051078, -122.314221);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 11,
            center: chicago
        }

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
            url: 'http://aeronnovation.ae/NoFlyZoneFile/doc.kml',
            preserveViewport: true


        });
        ctaLayer.setMap(map);

        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                                 position.coords.longitude);

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    map: map,
                    position: pos,
                    content: 'You are here'
                });

                map.setCenter(pos);
            }, function () {
                handleNoGeolocation(true);
            });
        } else {
            // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
            handleNoGeolocation(false);
        }
    }

    function handleNoGeolocation(errorFlag) {
        if (errorFlag) {
            var content = 'Error: The Geolocation service failed.';
        } else {
            var content = 'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.';
        }

        var options = {
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(60, 105),
            content: content
        };

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(options);
        map.setCenter(options.position);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KmlLayer doesn't allow access to the underlying polygon data.  You can do it with FusionTables (if you import your KML data) or a third party KML parser (like [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) or [geoxml-v3](https://code.google.com/archive/p/geoxml-v3/))

- [example using geoxml3](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_collection-map2e.html)
- [example using FusionTables](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_collection-map2e_FT.html)
- [example using geoxml3 with your data through a proxy](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geocodePointInPolygon_linkto.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/xmlProxy060215.asp?http://aeronnovation.ae/NoFlyZoneFile/doc.kml)